# i was trying to make a command that chnages the bots activity

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

EDIT: I JUST NEEDED TO PASS THE CLIENT

this is the code that i made in its own file

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot= new Discord.Client();
module.exports = {
    name: 'set' ,
    execute(message, args){
        if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_GUILD"))
        {
            if (args[2]==='picture')
                {const image=message.attachments.first().url;
                bot.user.setAvatar(image);}
            else if (args[2]==='activity')
            {
                let initial = message.content ;
                initial= initial.replace('asb set activity','').replace(args[3],'');
                bot.user.setActivity(initial, { type: args[3] });
            }
            else
                message.reply('invalid command');
        }
        else
            return message.reply('You can use this command only if u have permisions to manage the server');
    }
}
```

and this is the error

```
 bot.user.setActivity(initial, { type: args[3] });
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null
```

if i remove the bot client and use `client.message` it gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `bot` is a `new Discord.Client();`

What you should do instead is pass the client object from your index.js file to the command file and use that to set its activity.
Or you can get the client also with: `message.client` , so your code would be something like:

```
message.client.user.setActivity(...);
```